# How to count the Done status in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vue and I have a json file and the file looks like this

```
{
  "Task-1": {
    "Name": "Task 1",
    "Start": "2020-04-08",
    "End": "2020-04-17",
    "Issues": {
      "Issue-1": {
        "Name": "Issue 1",
        "issueStatus": "Done"
      },
      "Issue-2": {
        "Name": "Issue 2",
        "Status": "Done"
      },
      "Issue-3": {
        "Name": "Issue 3",
        "Status": "Done"
      },
      "Issue-4": {
        "Name": "Issue 4",
        "Status": "Done"
      },
      "Issue-5": {
        "Name": "Issue 5",
        "Status": "Done"
      },
      "Issue-6": {
        "Name": "Issue 6",
        "Status": "Done"
      }
    }
  },
  "Task-2": {
    "Name": "Task 2",
    "Start": "2020-04-08",
    "End": "2020-04-17",
    "Issues": {
      "Issue-1": {
        "Name": "Issue 1",
        "Status": "Done"
      },
      "Issue-2": {
        "Name": "Issue 2",
        "Status": "Done"
      },
      "Issue-3": {
        "Name": "Issue 3",
        "Status": "In Progress"
      },
      "Issue-4": {
        "Name": "Issue 4",
        "Status": "In Progress"
      },
      "Issue-5": {
        "Name": "Issue 5",
        "Status": "In Progress"
      },
      "Issue-6": {
        "Name": "Issue 6",
        "Status": "In Progress"
      }
    }
  },
}
```

What I would like to do is calculate how many `Done` issues there is per task.

This is what I have at the moment

Task.vue

```
getTasks(){

    $.each(this.tasks, function(key, value){

        var count = Object.keys(value.Issues).length;

        $.each(value.Issues, function(k, v){
            if(v.Status == "Done")
            {
                console.log(v.Status.length);
            }


        });
     });
},
```

This section

```
if(v.Status == "Done")
{
    console.log(v.Status.length);
}
```

finds all the issues that is done and this is where I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery instead of vue. In vue.js you can use computed property with JavaScript higher-order function to iterate through the json data and filter the elements. Then get the length.

See this example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    tasks: {
      "Task-1": {
        "Name": "Task 1",
        "Start": "2020-04-08",
        "End": "2020-04-17",
        "Issues": {
          "Issue-1": {
            "Name": "Issue 1",
            "issueStatus": "Done"
          },
          "Issue-2": {
            "Name": "Issue 2",
            "Status": "Done"
          },
          "Issue-3": {
            "Name": "Issue 3",
            "Status": "Done"
          },
          "Issue-4": {
            "Name": "Issue 4",
            "Status": "Done"
          },
          "Issue-5": {
            "Name": "Issue 5",
            "Status": "Done"
          },
          "Issue-6": {
            "Name": "Issue 6",
            "Status": "Done"
          }
        }
      },
      "Task-2": {
        "Name": "Task 2",
        "Start": "2020-04-08",
        "End": "2020-04-17",
        "Issues": {
          "Issue-1": {
            "Name": "Issue 1",
            "Status": "Done"
          },
          "Issue-2": {
            "Name": "Issue 2",
            "Status": "Done"
          },
          "Issue-3": {
            "Name": "Issue 3",
            "Status": "In Progress"
          },
          "Issue-4": {
            "Name": "Issue 4",
            "Status": "In Progress"
          },
          "Issue-5": {
            "Name": "Issue 5",
            "Status": "In Progress"
          },
          "Issue-6": {
            "Name": "Issue 6",
            "Status": "In Progress"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    doneLength: function() {
      // Map throught first keys
      const findDone = Object.keys(this.tasks).map(t => {
        // Get the issues object and filter based on required value (Done)
        return Object.keys(this.tasks[t].Issues).filter(i => {
          // return only matching values
          return this.tasks[t].Issues[i].Status == "Done";
        })
      });

      // flatten and get length
      return [].concat(...findDone).length;

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>{{doneLength}}</div>
```